# HTML5 Text Canvas rotate in case text width is larger than maximum width allowed

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, rotation

Friends, i'm finding rotating a text canvas object a bit tricky. The thing is, I'm drawing a graphic, but sometimes the width of each bar is smaller than the 'value' of that bar. So I have to ratate the 'value' 90 degrees. It will work in most cases.

I am doing the following

```
a function(x, y, text, maxWidth...)
var context = this.element.getContext('2d');

var metric = context.measureText(text); //metric will receive the measures of the text

if(maxWidth != null){
    if(metric.width > maxWidth) context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
}
context.fillText(text, x, y);
```

Ok, but it doesn't really work. Problems that I have seen: The text duplicates in different angles. The angles are not what I want (perhaps just a matter of trigonometry).

Well I just don't know what to do. I read something about methods like 'save' and 'restore' but I don't what to do with them. I've made some attempts but no one worked.

Would you help me with this, guys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to answer simply because there are a lot of concepts going on, so I've made you an example of what I think you'd like to do here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5UKE3/

The main part of it is this. I've put in a lot of comments to explain whats going on:

```
function drawSomeText(x, y, text, maxWidth) {
    //metric will receive the measures of the text
    var metric = ctx.measureText(text); 
    console.log(metric.width);

    ctx.save(); // this will "save" the normal canvas to return to
    if(maxWidth != null && metric.width > maxWidth) {
        // These two methods will change EVERYTHING
        // drawn on the canvas from this point forward
        // Since we only want them to apply to this one fillText,
        // we use save and restore before and after

        // We want to find the center of the text (or whatever point you want) and rotate about it
        var tx = x + (metric.width/2);
        var ty = y + 5;

        // Translate to near the center to rotate about the center
        ctx.translate(tx,ty);
        // Then rotate...
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        // Then translate back to draw in the right place!
        ctx.translate(-tx,-ty);
    }
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    ctx.restore(); // This will un-translate and un-rotate the canvas
}
```

To rotate around the right spot you have to translate to that spot, then rotate, then translate back.

Once you rotate the canvas the context is rotated *forever*, so in order to stop all your new drawing operations from rotating when you dont want them to, you have to use `save` and `restore` to "remember" the normal, unrotated context.

If anything else doesn't make sense let me know. Have a good time making canvas apps!

Comment: Be interesting to see this in css3 & js.