# html 5 canvas text

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Can we write on different angles on canvas? If yes, how? I want to write something on a click so need coordinates but when I use `context.rotate()` it doesn't  stay at a fixed position. If I click at the right of screen the text is very close to pointer but if I click on right it moves away. So what's the solution?

Comment: Post your code so far to http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer can be found here: [HTML5 Text Canvas rotate in case text width is larger than maximum width allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755050/html5-text-canvas-rotate-in-case-text-width-is-lager-than-maximum-width-allowed)

If you look at Simon's sample code http://jsfiddle.net/5UKE3/  you'll see where he saves the context, transforms the canvas then restores the context. This is key to what you are trying to achieve.

More on saving and restoring here: http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/

Comment: huh cant you tell me by yourself whats the reason behind saving the context

Comment: @john because clicking a link requires too much effort for you? :P